# HighChart spline live update data with old data issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am using Highchart to show my live activity on a current meter, I have 4 parameters like **Three phase voltage**, **Amp**, **Single Phase voltage** and **Total Power**
On initializing the chart I have ajax request to get last 20 records and appending them all in the chart like below

```
var dataset1 = [];
var dataset2 = [];
var dataset3 = [];
var dataset4 = [];  

var baseUrl = $('#base').val();
$.ajax({
        url: baseUrl+"dashboard/voltampGraph",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //console.log(data[i]._source.created);
          dataset1.push([data[i]._source.created,data[i]._source.tpv]);
          dataset2.push([data[i]._source.created,data[i]._source.tc]);
          dataset3.push([data[i]._source.created,data[i]._source.tv]);
          dataset4.push([data[i]._source.created,data[i]._source.tp]);
         }

        }
    });


var myChart = Highcharts.chart("linechart", {
  chart: {
    type: "spline"
  },
  title: {
    text: "Consumption"
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: "Values",
    }
  },
     xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Three phase voltage",
      data: dataset1
    },
    {
      name: "Amp",
      data: dataset2,
    },
    {
      name: "Single Phase voltage",
      data: dataset3,
    },
    {
      name: "Total Power",
      data: dataset4,
    }
  ]
});
```

There is no issue with this graph is looks good for the data we loaded, But I have to update the live data from the server which I am getting every 5 seconds using **$.post**

```
 setInterval(function() {
$.post(baseUrl+"dashboard/voltampMsg",function(data) {
    if(data.status=="success"){
        myChart.series[0].addPoint([data.data.created,data.data.tpv], true, true);
        myChart.series[1].addPoint([data.data.created,data.data.tc], true, true);
        myChart.series[2].addPoint([data.data.created,data.data.tv], true, true);
        myChart.series[3].addPoint([data.data.created,data.data.tp], true, true);
    }
},"json");
myChart.redraw();
}, 5000);
```

This also working fine as we load the data to the chart, but when we see visualization there is 2 spline for each parameter, means the old one which we loaded previously also visible in the chart. Please refer attached image[image]

The reason I am loading the 1st set of data is, I can't initialize the chart without any data if I assign empty data set then the next set of data's are not updating dynamically

Is there any way to update live data to highcharts without old data set? 
**Dataset on init:**

```
TPV :1531834002399 413.65
TC :1531834002399 0.279667
TV :1531834002399 227.8767
TP :1531834002399 43.671
TPV :1531833983914 413.6233
TC :1531833983914 0.279
TV :1531833983914 227.8367
TP :1531833983914 43.67167
TPV :1531833968099 413.62
TC :1531833968099 0.279
TV :1531833968099 227.75
TP :1531833968099 43.672
TPV :1531833952811 413.54
TC :1531833952811 0.277667
TV :1531833952811 227.78
TP :1531833952811 43.67134
TPV :1531833933943 413.1267
TC :1531833933943 0.283667
TV :1531833933943 227.5567
TP :1531833933943 43.671
TPV :1531833916201 414.9167
TC :1531833916201 0.288333
TV :1531833916201 228.57
TP :1531833916201 43.67267
TPV :1531833880529 412.6566
TC :1531833880529 0.272333
TV :1531833880529 227.2567
TP :1531833880529 43.673
TPV :1531833859568 412.6566
TC :1531833859568 0.272333
TV :1531833859568 227.2567
TP :1531833859568 43.673
TPV :1531833844129 412.5934
TC :1531833844129 0.271
TV :1531833844129 227.1733
TP :1531833844129 43.673
TPV :1531833825521 412.6167
TC :1531833825521 0.287667
TV :1531833825521 227.1833
TP :1531833825521 43.67033
```

**After setintervel**

```
TPV :1531834002399 413.65
TC :1531834002399 0.279667
TV :1531834002399 227.8767
TP :1531834002399 43.671
```

Comment: First off, for every point you add, you are redrawing the chart 5 times. You should set `addPoint(..., false, true)` for all addPoint. Also could you post a your initial dataset1 and the json you get in the setInterval ajax function for 1 interval?

Comment: I have updated the datasets, please check @ewolden

Comment: The setInterval timestamp start at the same time as the first timestamp in the inital dataset, you are basically redoing the chart from the start. I would suggest you continue from the last value. You can also avoid initialzing data, and do a check if there is 20 datapoints per series, if it is, then add with shift, if not, add without shift.

Comment: Here is an example how you could do it: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/9p68o2zf/ (obviously not with the ajax calls, but it should give you an idea)

Comment: We have to check `if(myChart.series[0].length == 20)` this in setinterval, it will fix the issue right? @ewolden

Comment: Actually, my bad. It should be `if(myChart.series[0].data.length == 20)`.